# Cancel Shipment Price in Prestashop when customer selects delivery by hand option

Tags: prestashop

In our online store we have a question like "Would you allow delivery of the product by hand to children with   cancer?" If the customer clicks option, the products in his basket are delivered to a children with cancer ilness later and the shipment price is decreased from the total ( recalculated) on the screen. Then customer pays the cost and the process ends.

Nowadays I am renewing my ebusiness-store. How can I do this in prestashop? I asked a friend he thinks that maybe we can do this bithday present module but we are really not sure how can we do this ? I even do not know which module is it? 
I will be very happy if I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really a programming question, but I think it will not be too hard to do this.  We have in our Prestashop website a shipping option of "Pick up item in store", with a shipping cost of $0.  If you have an option like this, then simply call it "Would you allow delivery of the product by hand to children with cancer?" instead.

Basically, under "Shipping" in the Prestashop back office, click on "Carriers", and add a new 'carrier' called "Would you allow delivery of the product by hand to children with cancer?"  Then under "Shipping"->"Shipping" you go to the section "Fees by carrier, geographical zone and ranges", and enter in $0 for everything.

The exact menu names seem to change with every Prestashop version, but this is the basic idea.  The buyer will see this option along with all the other carriers, so it's not quite as highlighted and split out as you might wish during the order process, but it won't require any modification of the PHP, and should do the job.

Comment: Hi, rossdavidh can you please upvote the question. I have issues related to the number of questions with 0 votes. This problems causes me not entering new questions.

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me vote for my own post.  Perhaps you can vote for it?

Comment: I asked for not the answer but the question. But no problem. The limitation is not active now. The problem is fixed for the time being. Thank you for your interest anyway :)

Comment: Voted for the question after my first comment, btw.  Thought I had left a second comment saying so, but I guess it didn't save.  Anyway, glad it worked out.